# is there a way to pull a different field in the same array

Tags: php

```
/**
*
* @param array $arrConfig
* @return $config
*/
function ParseConfig( $arrConfig ) {
    $config = array();
    foreach( $arrConfig as $line ) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if( $line != "" && $line[0] != "#" ) {
            $arrLine = explode( "=",$line );
            $config[$arrLine[0]] = ( count($arrLine) > 1 ? $arrLine[1] : true );
        }
    }
    return $config;
}






exec( 'cat '. RASPI_DNSMASQ_CONFIG, $return );
      $conf = ParseConfig($return);
      $arrRange = explode( ",", $conf['dhcp-range'] );
      $RangeStart = $arrRange[0];
      $RangeEnd = $arrRange[1];
      $RangeMask = $arrRange[2];
      preg_match( '/([0-9]*)([a-z])/i', $arrRange[3], $arrRangeLeaseTime );
```

this pulls from a file and adds the numbers to  a value

i want to do the same thing in the same file but pull the numbers from a line that starts with dhcp-option=6,

any help would be wonderful i am super new sorry

```
exec( 'cat '. RASPI_DNSMASQ_CONFIG, $return1 );
  $conf1 = ParseConfig($return1);
  $arrDNS = explode( ",", $conf1['dhcp-option=6,'] );
  $Dns = $arrDNS[0];
```

this is my shoot at it :( `$Dns` seems to be blank

inside the file it

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=192.168.110.20,192.168.110.120,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=6,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

here is where i am trying to pull string 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="code">Enter DNS adress seprate with , </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Dns" value="<?php echo $Dns; ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is `ParseConfig`? That's not a standard PHP function. Maybe you just need `$conf['dhcp-option=6']`

Comment: Post the output of `var_dump($conf);` in the question.

Comment: to be honest i have no idea how to do a var_dump and display it

Comment: Just put `var_dump($conf);` in the code. It displays the results, you copy them here.

Comment: You're using a function we've never heard of, how do you expect us to know what the result is?

Comment: Also, why are you using `exec(cat...)`? Just use `$return1 = file_get_contents(RASPI_DNSMASQ_CONFIG);`

Comment: i found the function ParseConfig and added it to my edit

Comment: So the line you want is in `$conf['dhcp-option']`

Comment: my goal is to set a sting from the file /etc/dnsmasq.conf
 and call it i don't care how i do it i want the string to be 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 or whatever comes after dhcp-option=6, the user can change the DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file('/etc/dnsmasq.conf');
$DNSTEST = $lines[2];
$Dns = substr($DNSTEST, 14);
```

I used this as a super simple way to do it this first 14 char never change

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="code">Enter DNS adress seprate with , </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Dns" value="<?php echo $Dns; ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

MY only issue now is i would rather like to use the ". RASPI_DNSMASQ_CONFIG" instead of the full file path but cant seem to get it working let me know if you have any ideas on that

[Working screen snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8YPZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to use `cat` to read files in PHP, it has built-in functions for that.

```
$return = file(RASPI_DNSMASQ_CONFIG, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE);
```

`ParseConfig()` uses the keyword before `=` as the key of the `$conf` array. So the option you want is in `$conf['dhcp-option']`.

```
$arrDNS = explode(',', $conf['dhcp-option']);
if ($arrDNS[0] == '6') {
    $dns = implode(',', array_splice($arrDNS, 1));
}
```

Note that because of the way your `ParseConfig()` works, you won't be able to parse different `dhcp-option=X` values. Array keys have to be unique, you can't have more than one `$conf['dhcp-option']`. It will always be the last one in the file.

Comment: i am still not getting a value

Comment: Does the file have multiple `dhcp-option` lines? As I said, this will only work if `dhcp-option=6` is the last one.

Comment: Don't use `ParseConfig()` if the config file has repeated options.

Comment: maybe i did something incorrectly. i need to keep the current and make a new one just for the DNS what should it look like

Comment: Write code similar to the code that's in `ParseConfig()`, but searches for what you want. I'm not going to write it for you.

Comment: Check if `$arrLine[0] == "dhcp-option"` then parse `$arrLine[1]` the way you want.

Comment: can you point me to a good place to study what i want to do i thank its over my head you have been amazing but i am just not get it all the way i feel like it should be more simple to pull line  3 and leave out dhcp-option=6, maybe the way i am trying to do it is over my head. is there away to pull line 3 and delete "dhcp-option=6,"?

Comment: I don't know what to recommend. There are many PHP tutorials, I don't know which are any good. And your need is pretty specific, it's hard to know which will go into details that will help you. It's just a matter of learning the language in general. If you can't do it yourself, you should hire an experienced programmer.

Comment: i think the issue could have been $return = file(RASPI_DNSMASQ_CONFIG, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINE); it pulls nothing i wonder why